# obout gridview postback databind

Tags: sql, asp.net, gridview, data-binding, obout

Hello i am working with visual studio , asp.net vb.net and using obout gridview 
my problem is that it aint updating after inserting new data ( it does only after reloading the page )
i am using the asp.net sql control for selection and insertion 
so after something like :

```
Protected Sub createCategoryBtn_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles createCategoryBtn.Click
.
.
.
 sql1.insert()
 sql1.databind() 
 grid1.databind() 
.
.
.
END SUB
```

i still cant see the new row ( only after reloading the page )
i noticed obout grid got rebind option on click in which u can open sql connection and probebly data bind the grid, but i was wondering if i can avoid doing that? ( if thats even the right way to do so with obout gridview )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `grid1.datasource = sql1` before `grid1.databind()`